# Organize lot and lof inside a table

Tags: table-of-contents

my supervisor asked us to create the report with a given template which follows the  problem. The template has list of figures and list of tables organized inside a table, as this. [image: provided template]

and my lof and lot comes in like this. [image: my lof and lot]

Comment: Would your supervisor be content just to have bold headings above the columns or are they fixated on having lines everywhere? Could you convince them that your version is much more readable?

Comment: he insisted that there must be lines everywhere.